# python numpy recarray stacking

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

How can I stack or join numpy recarrays without getting errors like:

```
    self.data = numpy.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays((self.data, data))# , asrecarray=True) # works
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py", line 747, in stack_arrays
    (dict(newdescr)[name], descr[1]))
TypeError: Incompatible type '<U72' <> '<U56'
```

I start with a dtype=object so I don't understand why its getting some things cast down to '

Comment: What are the types of `data` and `self.data` if you inspect them yourself? You could cast one or both of them to a different type (using `astype`) for this call.

Comment: I have cast them as far as I was concerned. I think I even tried with '<U100' but then they seem to get cut down to the max length of that particular array. I'll try to come up with a minimal example producing the errors ... it's a bit hard to work from just the error. I was just hoping I was doing something //completely// wrong and there was an easy fix.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg15088.html  What are the data sources for `data` and `self.data`?

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere by avoiding using '<U100' which is some sort of lower level type and using 'a100' instead (byte string). This is after reading 1) a through d at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html ... I think I just RTFM'd myself! I somewhere had been going to the tech docs directly instead of the user guide which is more helpful to me at this point.